# Removing files at different intervals with Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I've seen questions similar to this, however I decided to post as I have not seen one that holds the nuances that I'm seeking.

I'm looking for a way to add a clause that leaves alone empty files and then certain files that are user maintained.

1. leave any and all empty folders alone
2. ignore specified folders and file types

So far I have this:

```
Start-Transcript C:\Temp3\filecleanup.log -Append
$folder_path = "[[-Path] <String[K:\]>"
# replace -90 with days before current date to be deleted
$1m = "-30"
$3m = "-90"
$6m = "-180"
$12m = "-360"
$18m = "-540"
$curr_date = Get-Date

#script for 30 days
$del_date1m = $curr_date.AddDays($1m)
Get-ChildItem $folder_path -Recurse [-Exclude <file folders, Applications, 
*.bat>] | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt $del_date1m } | Remove-Item -
Force -Verbose

#script for 90 days
$del_date3m = $curr_date.AddDays($3m)
Get-ChildItem $folder_path -Recurse [-Exclude <file folders, Applications, 
*.bat>] | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt $del_date3m } | Remove-Item -
Force -Verbose

#script for 180 days
$del_date1m = $curr_date.AddDays($6m)
Get-ChildItem $folder_path -Recurse [-Exclude <file folders, Applications, 
*.bat>] | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt $del_date6m } | Remove-Item -
Force -Verbose

#script for 360 days
$del_date1m = $curr_date.AddDays($12m)
Get-ChildItem $folder_path -Recurse [-Exclude <file folders, Applications, 
*.bat>] | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt $del_date12m } | Remove-Item 
-Force -Verbose

#script for 540 days
$del_date1m = $curr_date.AddDays($18m)
Get-ChildItem $folder_path -Recurse [-Exclude <file folders, Applications, 
*.bat>] | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -lt $del_date18m } | Remove-Item 
-Force -Verbose
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: did you check the script?

Answer (score 0):

This script uses hash tables for all the month you have to periods for:

The variable `$exclude_file_types` can contain directories and also endings of files like *.bat.

First it finds non-empty directories and then it uses `foreach` to cycle within them.  Second loop uses the hash table to cycle through all the months.

**EDIT:**

```
# if you want to recurse set to true
$recurse = $true

$folder_path = 'C:\prg'
# hash table to access it one month -> $time_definition.1m
$time_definition=@{'1m'="-30"; '3m'="-90"; '6m'="-180"; '12m'="-360"; '18m'="-540"}
Write-host "$time_definition.1m"

# Directories should be with full path
$excluded_directories = @("C:\prg\PowerShell\_Snippets\search_files_or_directories\test")
# Exclude any extension
$excluded_file_types = @("*.bat", "*.cmd", "*.ps1")


# Get all non-empty directories
# If you want to disable the top directory with the whole tree beneath it remove the -Recurse option
$get_full_directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder_path -Recurse:$recurse -exclude $excluded_directories | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Where-Object {!$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0}
#search in those directories for all periods
foreach ($search_dir in $get_full_directories) {
    foreach ($time in $time_definition.GetEnumerator()) {
        # to check
        #write-host 'time_months:'$($time.Name);
        write-host 'Currently writing for these months:'$($time.Name);
        Get-ChildItem -Path $search_dir -recurse -exclude $excluded_file_types | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $FALSE} | where {$_.LastAccessTime -lt (get-date).adddays($time_definition.$($time.Name))} | Remove-Item -Force -Verbose
    }
}
```

I have tested all the code except the last pipe `| Remove-Item -Force -Verbose` but that should work quite well.